# SQL query SUM() AND GROUP BY for 2 columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, report, row, percentage

I am using Microsoft Sql Server management studio.

I have had mixed success creating a tax report for a particular type of invoice that I have.

I have amounts under 6%, other amounts under 13.5% and the last amount has a complete total of both 6% and 13.5%.

I have got my answer in the results, but two different rows for each invoice are displayed. One is for 6% values and the other for 13.5% values.

I need to somehow merge these two rows into one single row for each invoice.

My Sql query is as follows:

```
SELECT  tran_no ,
        tran_date ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(edetail_amt)
          WHERE     edetail_taxid = '6008U_='
        ) AS '6% amt' ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(edetail_per)
          WHERE     edetail_taxid = '6008U_='
        ) AS '6% vat' ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(edetail_amt)
          WHERE     edetail_taxid = '6008U_>'
        ) AS '13.5% amt' ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(edetail_per)
          WHERE     edetail_taxid = '6008U_>'
        ) AS '13.5% vat' ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(edetail_amt + edetail_per)
          WHERE     edetail_taxid IN ( '6008U_=', '6008U_>' )
        ) AS 'Net Total'
FROM    h_edetail
        INNER JOIN h_tran ON edetail_tranid = tran_kid
WHERE   tran_trantype = 'PI'
        AND tran_date = '2016-11-03 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY tran_no ,
        tran_date ,
        edetail_taxid
ORDER BY tran_no;
```

A screenshot of the query along with the results are as follows:

[image: Query and results]

Comment: post the query as text

Comment: select tran_no,tran_date,(select sum(edetail_amt) where edetail_taxid='6008U_=') as '6% amt',
(select sum(edetail_per) where edetail_taxid='6008U_=') as '6% vat',
(select sum(edetail_amt) where edetail_taxid='6008U_>') as '13.5% amt',
(select sum(edetail_per) where edetail_taxid='6008U_>') as '13.5% vat',
(select sum(edetail_amt + edetail_per) where edetail_taxid in ('6008U_=','6008U_>')) as 'Net Total' 
from h_edetail inner join h_tran on edetail_tranid=tran_kid where tran_trantype='PI' and 
tran_date='2016-11-03 00:00:00.000' group by tran_no,tran_date,edetail_taxid order by tran_no

Comment: Nothing in your query is called "invoice", so the question is totally unclear.  That is why sample data and desired results are so important.

Comment: This question could really benefit from a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as Gordon suggests. we don't know the shape of the raw data being fetched from the objects in your `FROM` clause, or even for sure which tables/views specific columns are from.

Comment: tran_no is the invoice number, tran_date is the date of the invoice and edetail_amt is the amount share in the total invoice amount and edetail_per is the percentage tax amount against the edetail_amt of the respective tax amounts

Comment: h_tran is the table in which my invoice number,date and amounts and h_edetail is the table in which my tax amounts(bifurcated) gets stored

Comment: will try to give u a sample query now

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
SELECT tran_no,
       tran_date,
        Sum(case when edetail_taxid = '6008U_=' then edetail_amt else 0 end) AS '6% amt',
        Sum(case when edetail_taxid = '6008U_=' then edetail_per else 0 end) AS '6% vat',
        Sum(case when edetail_taxid = '6008U_>' then edetail_amt else 0 end) AS '13.5% amt',
        Sum(case when edetail_taxid = '6008U_>' then edetail_per else 0 end) AS '13.5% vat',
        Sum(case when edetail_taxid IN ( '6008U_=', '6008U_>' ) then edetail_amt + edetail_per else 0 end) AS 'Net Total'
FROM   h_edetail
       INNER JOIN h_tran
               ON edetail_tranid = tran_kid
WHERE  tran_trantype = 'PI'
       AND tran_date = '2016-11-03 00:00:00.000'
GROUP  BY tran_no,
          tran_date
ORDER  BY tran_no
```

Because of `select sum(edetail_amt) where edetail_taxid='6008U_='` you are forced to add `edetail_taxid` in `group by` that is the reason for duplicate records. You can do that by adding `case` inside `SUM` aggregate